# jQPlot - remove vertical grid lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jqplot

I am using jqPlot as my charting framework and have numerous charts in my application, primarily line and stacked bar charts.

I now have a requirement to only show the horizonal grid lines on these charts and do not see any options in jqPlot to do this.

There is a `showGridline` option but that disables the grid lines entirely.

Is it possible to remove only the vertical grid lines in jqPlot and continue to show the horizontal ones?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I figured it out. You can apply `showGridline` to a single axis by doing the following:

```
axes:{
    xaxis: {
       tickOptions:{
          showGridline: false
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

To remove the grid line on the X-axis :

```
axes : {
    xaxis : {
       tickOptions : {
           showGridline : false
       }
    }
}
```

To remove the grid line on the Y-axis :

```
axes : {
    yaxis : {
       tickOptions : {
           showGridline : false
       }
    }
}
```

To remove the grid line on both axes :

```
axes : {
    xaxis : {
       tickOptions : {
           showGridline : false
       }
    },
    yaxis : {
       tickOptions : {
           showGridline : false
       }
    }
}
```

or

```
grid : {
    drawGridlines: false
}
```