# how to show dotted grid lines in jqplot instead of solid lines

Tags: jquery, jqplot

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Our data renderer function, returns an array of the form:
  // [[[x1, sin(x1)], [x2, sin(x2)], ...]]
  var sineRenderer = function() {
    var data = [[]];
    for (var i=0; i<13; i+=0.5) {
      data[0].push([i, Math.sin(i)]);
    }
    return data;
  };

  // we have an empty data array here, but use the "dataRenderer"
  // option to tell the plot to get data from our renderer.
  var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1',[],{
      title: 'Sine Data Renderer',
      dataRenderer: sineRenderer
  });
});
```

> In this chart i have to set dotted grid lines in background.
>   is this possible to draw dotted grid lines in jqplot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether an easier way to accomplish this exists, but this works:

Open `jquery.jqplot.js`. In function `$.jqplot.CanvasGridRenderer.prototype.draw` add line `ctx.setLineDash([1, 5]);` after line `ctx.save();`. Then just minimize the file, save it as `jquery.jqplot.min.js` (or apply those changes directly on minimized version) and you're good to go.

Bear in mind that all your charts will have dotted lines now. If that's a problem, then you would need to add a new property to `Grid` class like `lineDash` and process it accordingly in `$.jqplot.CanvasGridRenderer.prototype.draw`.

[image]

Comment: thanks it worked . but if i have to remove vertical lines , can u suggest me ? –  Tarika 6 mins ago

Comment: @Tarika already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126889/jqplot-remove-vertical-grid-lines